# How can I perform loop closure in graph SLAM?

Tags: ros, slam, g2o

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to implement graph based SLAM and I am using g2o for backend. So far I have

1. Constructed a graph using laser data i.e pose-pose graph
2. I dont have any odometry source so I used [Scan_matcher](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_scan_matcher) to estimate pose constraints

Now I dont understand how to add and loop closures in my graph. I read some papers but the implementation details are naive to me. I would be thankful if someone could point me in the right direction
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259543/how-can-i-perform-loop-closure-in-graph-slam-?/) by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 225 on 2017-04-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use [slam_karto_g2o](https://github.com/sauravag/slam_karto_g2o). It uses open_karto for the front-end and g2o for the backend. Other options are slam_karto and nav2d, both of which use sparse_bundle_adjustment for the backend.

---

Originally posted by [Saurav Agarwal](https://answers.ros.org/users/4339/saurav-agarwal/) with karma: 246 on 2017-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're after a well working graph SLAM solution (without requiring specifically the use of g2o), [cartographer](https://github.com/googlecartographer/cartographer) and it's ROS integration [cartographer_ros](https://github.com/googlecartographer/cartographer_ros) is the obvious approach to try. It's 2D and 3D capable, provides good performance and has very responsive support.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-08-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) on 2017-08-15**:
I will give it a try. Thnx :)